# Feasibility of rsyncing the whole Plone production server running Ubuntu once in a day

Tags: ubuntu, plone, rsync, zodb

Has anyone experience of doing full VM snapshot or rsync back-ups with Plone? We have a server running several separate Zope application server worth of around 10-20 GB ZODB data and blobs.

- Would it be possible to duplicate the server by rsynching the whole server filesystem to a replicate machine once in a day?

This would provide "barebone high availability" where in the case of server breakage one could just switch the production IP to the back-up server.

The issues here are

- Can rsync delta algorithm cleverly copy append-only Data.fs files or does it copy the whole Data.fs every time? Data.fs and blobs are the only data changing on the server running Plone sites.
- Is rsync fast enough for calculating deltas for the whole server file system once in a day
- Does rsync cause too much stress to the system when it is running
- Do one need to run something more advanced over rsync to speed up the process (e.g. Duplicity)
- Does Ubuntu system partition has something which must be excluded from rsync

As far as I know live ZODB Data.fs copies are ok due to their append-only nature.

The benefits of such replication method would

- Very simple to set-up: No advanced replication knowledge beyond normal Linux sysadmin knowledge needed

The data in our case is not that critical. We are fine if we can restore 1-2 old back-ups as long as the replication takes over within one day.

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, rsync will be able to copy the Data.fs data over incrementally; it is an append only method, after all.

You do run the risk that the last in-progress transaction is incomplete when being copied over by rsync, but Zope is smart enough to ignore incomplete transactions like that.

rsync will have to do a lot of work to find out where to start copying in the Data.fs though, as it doesn't know that the format is append only. So on every run, it'll analyse the full file from the start, which would consume some CPU and disk access resources.

Perhaps using a combination of [repozo](http://wiki.zope.org/ZODB/FileStorageBackup) and rsync would be a better solution? Run repozo to create snapshots (which are much more efficient to create, as repozo *does* know about the append-only nature of a Data.fs), rsync *those* over, and 'restore' your cold failover server from these backups automatically. With [`collective.recipe.backup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.backup) including repozo in your buildout is a snap.